# Ansible list concatenation in combination with "default" filter

Tags: ansible, jinja2

all

in my inventory i'm using three vars at different levels:

```
 all/vars: 
 common_configs:
   - src: cfg.a
     dest: dest_a
 group_vars/vars:
 group_configs:
   - src: cfg.b
     dest: dest_b
 host_vars/vars: 
 host_configs:
   - src: cfg.c
     dest: dest_c
```

finally i need all cfg's to be deployed to target host. I use the next code:

```
 - copy:
     src: '{{ item.src }}'
     dest: '{{ item.dest }}'
   with_items:
      - '{{ common_configs + group_configs + host_configs }}'
```

All works, but in my case only common_configs is mandatory, so when either group_configs or/and host_configs are undefined - i'm receiving an error.
I tried to use default(omit) filter:

```
   with_items:
      - '{{ common_configs + group_configs + host_configs|default(omit) }}'
```

But i've got another error:

```
FAILED! => {"msg": "Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({{ common_configs + group_configs + host_configs|default(omit) }}): can only concatenate list (not \"str\") to list"}
```

What is the true way to omit undefined vars in such case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use the `default` filter to replace undefined variables with an empty list in your expression:

```
with_items:
   - '{{ common_configs + group_configs|default([]) + host_configs|default([]) }}'
```

Comment: Wow. Very simple and  obviously but It didn't occur to me... Thanks